# Using variable in sql postdeployment build script?

Tags: sql, msbuild, sqlcmd, database-project

What I would like to be able to do, is to be able to **create a publising xml script in Visual Studio database project that defines a variable, that will be used to compose a script**.

My problem is that I get a Error:  "SQL72008: Variable DeployType is not defined." if I don´t define the variable in the post deployment script like this ":setvar DeployType "varchar(100)"

When I run the publish.xml the DeployType parameter is rightly set at the top of the generated script **BUT** that value get overridden with the ":setvar DeployType "varchar(100)". So to make this work I would need to manually remove that line before running this script.

So the question is **How can I let the project build and be able to publish without defaulting the setvar variable in the postdeployment script?**

[image]

This is the content of my PostDeployment.sql file **that does not build without defaulting the DeployType variable**

```
--The line causing my problems. I would like to skip it somehow.
:setvar DeployType "varchar(100)"

Print 'Always include core'
:r ..\Data\Core\_BaseCore.sql

--Conditionaly add based on DeployType comming from the publishing.xml
IF ('$(DeployType)' = 'A')
BEGIN
:r ..\Data\A\_BaseKnap.sql
END
ELSE IF ('$(DeployType)' = 'B')
BEGIN
:r ..\Data\B\_BaseB.sql
END
```

This is the content in the Database.publish.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <PropertyGroup>
   <IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
   <TargetDatabaseName>db name</TargetDatabaseName>
   <DeployScriptFileName>Database.sql</DeployScriptFileName>
   <ProfileVersionNumber>1</ProfileVersionNumber>
   <TargetConnectionString>Connection string</TargetConnectionString>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
   <SqlCmdVariable Include="DeployType">
     <Value>B</Value>
   </SqlCmdVariable>
 </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When I publish this to a script file **this is the generated script** to be run against the database I get (lots of stuff removed not needed).

```
:setvar DeployType "B"

--This nulls out the DeployType set before
:setvar DeployType "varchar(100)"

Print 'Always include core'
:r ..\Data\Core\_BaseCore.sql

--Conditionaly add based on DeployType comming from the publishing.xml
IF ('$(DeployType)' = 'A')
BEGIN
:r ..\Data\A\_BaseKnap.sql
END
ELSE IF ('$(DeployType)' = 'B')
BEGIN
:r ..\Data\B\_BaseB.sql
END
```

And running this (in e.g Sql Manager) the result is

```
Print 'Always include core'
```

where it doesn't go into the IF statements because it has been defaulted.

Hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I know this is a bit old thread, but here is the answer:

Click the properties on you database project and navigate to the "SQLCMD Variables" window. Define your `$(DeployType)` variable in the SQLCMD Variables table. This will allow the project to compile and hence you can (and actually need) remove the line `:setvar DeployType "varchar(100)"` from the script itself.[image]

Comment: I have a very related question that you might have an answer for me also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42846424/how-not-to-include-sql-file-content-when-publishing

Comment: I also discovered that the project will fail to build if you don't add a default value

Comment: Thanks for this answer and ...sigh... don't edit the Publish.xml file directly like I did. This makes much more sense now.