# How not to include sql file content when publishing?

Tags: sql, msbuild, sqlcmd, database-project, dacpac

I have a question that is very similar to an older question of mine [Using variable in sql postdeployment build script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178189/using-variable-in-sql-postdeployment-build-script)
 But now I don´t want to do an if/else and have the sql code in my published script. I don´t want to share information beetween customers.

So... here goes

- I have a database project in Visual Studio.
- I also have 2 customers with different needs

I know I can

- use post.deployment script to include content of sql files I need by setting a varible in Project.Properties."SQLCMD Variables".

[image]

And then use it like this in Script.PostDeployment.sql

```
:r ..\$(Customer)Setup.sql
```

Where I have 2 files

- Customer1Setup.sql
- Customer2Setup.sql

And then I set the SQLCMD Variable as $(Customer) "Customer1" or "Customer2" and only the one I had put in the SQLCMD is included.

**But** when I want to use the variable in the **publishing** window **the default one overrides it**

[image]

I know I can do this somewho in a build script but I want to know if I can use the current tools and just create  Customer1.publish.xml and Customer2.publish.xml files so that I know that something that is for Customer1 does not go with the script if published to Customer2.

**EDIT 1**:

I created a public [GitHub repository](https://github.com/sturlath/SQLCMDConditionalFiles) to try to address my problem. Hopefully somebody can take a look and edit it to work.

**EDIT 2**:

This is the result from my test project (same as my real one) where in every one of the 3 tests I have there result in the same. All the "stuff" in Customer2/Customer3 is included in the result. If this is supposed to work there is some switch or setting I´m missing in my setup (VS2015 database project)

```
SET NOEXEC ON
Print 'This print statement should not be in the publishing script if     Customer variable is not customer1'
print 'Customer1 stuff from Customer1.sql'
SET NOEXEC OFF

IF('$(Customer)' <> 'customer2')
SET NOEXEC ON
Print 'This print statement should not be in the publishing script if     Customer variable is not customer2'
print 'Customer2 stuff from Customer2.sql'
SET NOEXEC OFF

IF('$(Customer)' <> 'customer3')
SET NOEXEC ON
Print 'This print statement should not be in the publishing script if    Customer variable is not customer3'
print 'Customer3 stuff from Customer3.sql'
SET NOEXEC OFF
```

**EDIT 3**

So if I visualize this little better
This is what I **want** to get
[image]

But this is **what I get**
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional logic in PostDeployment.sql script using SQLCMD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151021/conditional-logic-in-postdeployment-sql-script-using-sqlcmd)

Comment: What is the problem with the conditional logic being part of the script?

Comment: Like I said in the chat : Sometimes the client gets the script to setup in their environment and then I don´t want any other customer-specific-things in that script. I´m just trying to make this automatic solution. But l´m thinking this could/should just be done in a build script (Cake?). But I kinda find it strange that this is not built into the tools. Maybe I should write an VS database extension?

Answer (score 0):

The below won't work as per expectations:

```
:r ..\$(Customer)Setup.sql
```

Instead though, you could use the `IF ELSE` approach:

```
IF ('$(Customer)'='customer1')
BEGIN
    :r .\script_customer1.sql
END
IF ('$(Customer)'='customer2')
BEGIN
    :r .\script_customer2.sql
END
```

After a bit more research I found [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34145220/1223982). It turns out the above would not work in case you use `GO` in your scripts. So could use the below:

```
IF ('$(Customer)'<>'customer1')
    SET NOEXEC ON

:r .\script_customer1.sql
SET NOEXEC OFF

IF ('$(Customer)'<>'customer2')
    SET NOEXEC ON

:r .\script_customer2.sql
SET NOEXEC OFF
```

Comment: Ok awesome! I have searched and searched but have not found the the NOEXEC part! I will try this out rightaway.

Comment: Ok this is not working. Or at least I´m not doing it right. I added a link to a public GitHub repo where you can test this and hopefully update if possible. I´m counting on you Alex :-)

Comment: Both options from the answer have been tested. Have you tried just the "Generate Script" option and then examining it and possibly run in sql management studio?

Comment: Then I´m missing something else in the setup. I updated the question and here is a link to my GitHub (with explanations) https://github.com/sturlath/SQLCMDConditionalFiles. Can you get that to work? Would realy love to get this to work...

Comment: In your github, you comparing to the lowercase 'customer1', but in the publish files you use '<Value>Customer1</Value>'.
Also the `Customer1.sql` has: `print 'Customer1 stuff from Customer2.sql'` inside.

Comment: The output from running `Customer1.publish.xml` is correct in my eyes:
`This print statement should not be in the publishing script if Customer 
variable is not customer1`    

`Customer1 stuff from Customer2.sql`   

`Common stuff...`   

`Update complete.`

Comment: And do you NOT see the content from the Customer2.sql and Customer3.sql in there? p.s updated github thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138479/discussion-between-alex-m-and-sturla).