# VS2017 DBPROJ SQLCMD Variable Test for Literal Value

Tags: sql-server-2017, dbproj

I want to conditionally run a post-deploy script. My script (currently) looks like this:

```
declare @tier nvarchar(100) = $(tier)
if( @tier = 'TEST' )
    begin
    :r .\ConfigSeedData.TEST.sql
    end
```

I have defined the variable in the project file, as detailed in [Using variable in sql postdeployment build script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178189/using-variable-in-sql-postdeployment-build-script). The variable is (currently) defined as `TEST` (no quotes, but I've tried it with quotes, too).

However, no matter how I try to twist my syntax, I keep getting this error:
`.Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 875 Invalid column name 'TEST'.`

How do I check a sqlcmd variable for a literal value, not a column?

I have tried adding the square brackets around the $(), tried accessing the value directly (without assigning to nvarchar).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, you need to put single quotes around the variable use. To make the above work, the code would be:

```
if( '$(tier)' = 'TEST' )
```

So even though it looks like you're using the literal "`$(tier)`", it's actually being pulled out of the quotes, interpreted, and put back in.